# Characterize projective scheme via its line bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $l$ be a line bundle on $X$. What can we say about the line bundle $l$ that will make $X$ projective? Or is there nothing one can say?

If this fails, how can we characterize a projective scheme in terms of its bundles?

I am interested since I want to know the bundle-theoretic significance of projective space. This should also be related to intersection theory on projective space, via the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem.

Comment: The key phrase here is “ample line bundle.” But I think the question in the title and the body differ. Could you clarify?

Comment: @SamirCanning I changed "space" to "scheme" in the title.